# Approximating the unit tangent vectors of discrete data!

Tags: numerical-methods, vectors, tangent-line, bezier-curve

I do have a set of discrete data of `n` points $(P_{1}, P_{2}, …., P_{n})$ in 3d space, each point $P_{i}$ has 3 components for `(x, y, z)`. 
I’m trying to fit a sequence of cubic Bezier curves to these data using an algorithm provided by **[Andrew S. Glassner. Graphics Gems I. Academic Press Inc., 1990 ]**.

To do that I need to be able to calculate the tangent vector at each point $P_{i}$, including the two endpoints $P_{1}$ and $P_{n}$. 
What I’m currently doing is approximating the tangent vector in $P_{1}$ by a vector going form $P_{1}$ to $P_{2}$ as $(P_{2}-P_{1})$, and in $P_{n}$ by a vector going from $P_{n}$ to $P_{n-1}$ as $(P_{n-1}-P_{n})$, and in any intermediate point $P_{i}$ by a vector from $P_{i-1}$ to $P_{i+1}$ as $(P_{i+1} - P_{i-1})$ . This solution works as desired for most of the cases, but when the data points are too far away from each other, my approximation of the tangent vectors in the two endpoints $P_{1}$ and $P_{n}$ becomes very rough, and the error of fitted curves is therefore very big.

So I thought I'll post this here to see if somebody could have an idea for how to get better approximation of tangent vectors. Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: check out "Catmull-Rom spline" to see if it fits your purpose as it will also produce a sequence of cubic Bezier curves. Also, make sure you use centripetal paramatrization as it will generally produce good result for unevenly-distributed data points,

Comment: @fang Thanks for the suggestions! I think the above mentioned algorithm meets my needs. And for the parameters, I generate them initially with Chord-Length parameterization, that is also a very rough approximation, but I keep optimizing them iteratively using closest point on Bezier curve, which eventually gives me almost the exact parameters values.

Comment: @fang The only weakness in the above algorithm "in my opinion" is its way of approximating the unit tangent vectors. In the book they suggest **fitting a least-squares line to the points in the neighborhood of the endpoints, or by averaging vectors from the endpoints to the next n points, and so on**. In practice I found the procedures I described above work much better than those suggestions in the book, but not for all cases as you can see!
I still believe there are better ways to get around this, but haven't figured out any yet!!

Comment: **Update:** Well, it turned out that I already use Centripetal method for parameterization! I found from some online resources that the only difference between Chord-Length and Centripetal method is that for calculating the length of data polygon the first one uses a simple square-distance where the second one uses the euclidean-distance, which I was also using.

Comment: Chord-length method use distance between data points in parametrization while centripetal method uses square root of distance.